# MOODLE - Portable Document Format

Tags: moodle

Looking for download (PDF, CSV) the data from moodle custompage. Are there API function, need to call for downloading the data from custompage. The custompage has a table data:

custompage

```
$table = new html_table();
$table->head = array('course', 'users');
$table->attributes['class'] = 'table';

$sql = "SELECT c.fullname, count(cc.userid) AS 'completed'
        FROM {course_completions} cc JOIN {course} ON c.id = cc.course WHERE cc.timestarted > 0
        GROUP BY c.fullname ";

$mds = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);    
foreach ($mds as $m) {
    $table->data[] = new html_table_row(array(implode(array($m->fullname. $m->lastname)), 
                           $m->completed ));
}                              
echo html_writer::table($table);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a basic PDF

```
require_once($CFG->libdir . '/pdflib.php');

$doc = new pdf();

$doc->AddPage();

$output = html_writer::table($table);

$doc->writeHTML($output);

$doc->Output('filename.pdf');
```

There is a better example in the Moodle source here - /lib/tests/other/pdflibtestpage.php

For CSV

```
require_once($CFG->libdir . '/csvlib.class.php');

csv_export_writer::download_array('filename.csv, $mds);
```

Both of the above should be before printing anything to the screen so they are downloaded.

Also in your SQL, you should use `GROUP BY c.id` because the course fullname isn't unique.

Comment: Thank You Russell England. Your support is really appreciated!

Comment: Exception - TCPDF ERROR: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file